# I was running my nextJs server, all of a sudden an error is coming,

Tags: next.js

npm run dev

> active-class-name@1.0.0 dev D:\Aman\aquadsoft\ept-react\new\ept-react
> next

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Aman\aquadsoft\ept-react\new\ept-react\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! active-class-name@1.0.0 dev: `next`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the active-class-name@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AMAN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-07-11T05_00_56_071Z-debug.log

Comment: To resolve this, I have already tried, installing next globalling, re installing next, re-clone the project and run npm install and try.

Answer (score 0):

It worked finally, with removing the npm and npm-cache folder and then running command

npm install -g npm@latest

After that installed nextJs globally and run npm install inside my project directory.
It worked.